# Como posso fazer uma imagem ao passar o mouse ela aparece um texto no centro da imagem?

Tags: html, css

Como posso fazer uma imagem ao passar o mouse ela aparece um texto no centro da imagem? com o código css, ou outro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```css
figure {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

figure figcaption {
  display: none;  
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;  
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


figure:hover figcaption {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/macaque.jpg" alt="Macaque in the trees">
  <figcaption class="center">A cheeky macaque, Lower Kintaganban River, Borneo.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado :)